# How to install Xubuntu from a hard drive instead of a DVD or a USB stick?

Tags: installation, xubuntu, hard-drive

I have an old computer and I want to install Xubuntu 13.04 on it. The problem is it has no DVD drive (only a CD one) and it won't boot from a USB stick (it boots from the CD-ROM and/or the HDD only). However, there are 2 HDDs, a 40 GB and a 20 GB one.

Facing this problem, I thought maybe I could create a USB stick installation, as usual, copy all files to the second HDD, boot the machine from this second HDD and install Xubuntu on the first HDD. In other words, I would be using the second HDD as a DVD or a USB stick installation, in theory.

Is that possible? If so, is it that simple, I just copy all files from the USB stick to the second HDD and boot the machine? Or do I have to do anything else?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The issue is you will need to make the drive bootable for Ubuntu/Xubuntu. Do you have a USB enclosure or an open drive bay on a working computer? You could take one of the drives and put it into an enclosure and make a LiveUSB with it, then pop it back into the machine. Alternatively, you can use a working machine and a LiveUSB/CD and install the OS to one of the hard drives then just move it...

Comment: I see your point, Kendor. I do have an external USB case in which I can put either a HDD or a CD/DVD drive. I'll create a LiveUSB targeting this device. Unfortunately, I don't have another machine, besides my laptop computer. But you gave me a good and possible solution. I'll try it right away. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Just for the record, your suggestion worked like a charm, Kendor. Thank you very much for your time. :)